# How can I convert a three-column layout to a single unordered list for mobile?

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I'm working on a responsive web page, which currently has 3 divs containing further divs. These display on the screen as 3 floated columns

However when the screen size is 700px and below, I'd like this html to change to an unordered list, not 3 floated columns

I know you can change the CSS to be responsive, but is it possible to change the html? (or is there a better way to achieve the desired result?)

```
<section id="links">
  <div id="links_1">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
      <p>Text example 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
      <p>Text example 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 3</h3>
      <p>Text example 3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 4</h3>
      <p>Text example 4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 5</h3>
      <p>Text example 5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 6</h3>
      <p>Text example 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="links_2">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 7</h3>
      <p>Text example 7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 8</h3>
      <p>Text example 8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 9</h3>
      <p>Text example 9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 10</h3>
      <p>Text example 10</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 11</h3>
      <p>Text example 11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 12</h3>
      <p>Text example 12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="links_3">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 13</h3>
      <p>Text example 13</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 14</h3>
      <p>Text example 14</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 15</h3>
      <p>Text example 15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 16</h3>
      <p>Text example 16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why can't you just have your columns stack for mobile? It's not clear what your use case is, so it's hard to offer suggestions. I don't see the problem.

Comment: You'd also need to show your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation I'm working on and chose to go the flexbox route. Here's the solution I've come up with:

1. Write your HTML and CSS with a mobile-first approach. This means your HTML should be one uninterrupted list; no manual breaking into columns. Something like:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    ...
    <li>Item 15</li>
</ul>
```

2. Now that you have a proper list, use media queries to change properties as the viewport expands:

```css
@media (min-width: 701px) {
    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        height: 9rem;
    }
    
    li {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
    }
}
```

Now, adding on to this will be things like margin and padding resets, box-sizing (if needed), etc. The major "drawback" is that you have to specify a height for the list - otherwise the list items will continue to run in a single column as the parent `<ul>` expands to accommodate its content. It isn't until the list items run out of height in the parent that they will begin to wrap into another column.

Note: this should work in IE10+ and all other browsers approximately 3 years and newer.

Answer (score 0):

by jquery you can handle window resize event as:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  //
});
```

you can get elements and reorder or change them inside the function, css doesn't let you change html, but if you want to do it by CSS, [read this article](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) about css float

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it responsively even with html5 by adding the style etiquete and using the percentages to adjust it responsively

```html
<section id="links" style="width:50%;height:50%">
  <div id="links_1">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
      <p>Text example 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
      <p>Text example 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 3</h3>
      <p>Text example 3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 4</h3>
      <p>Text example 4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 5</h3>
      <p>Text example 5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 6</h3>
      <p>Text example 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="links_2">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 7</h3>
      <p>Text example 7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 8</h3>
      <p>Text example 8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 9</h3>
      <p>Text example 9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 10</h3>
      <p>Text example 10</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 11</h3>
      <p>Text example 11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 12</h3>
      <p>Text example 12</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="links_3">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 13</h3>
      <p>Text example 13</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 14</h3>
      <p>Text example 14</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 15</h3>
      <p>Text example 15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 16</h3>
      <p>Text example 16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However if I do it this way, it makes the content 50% regardless of screen size?

Answer (score 0):

With a flexbox and a media query you can solve this. If you want to change the HTML you would still need CSS and or JS to hide/ show the specifc HTML part.

```css
#links {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

#links div {
  flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #links div {
    width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<section id="links">
  <div id="links_1">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
      <p>Text example 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
      <p>Text example 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 3</h3>
      <p>Text example 3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 4</h3>
      <p>Text example 4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 5</h3>
      <p>Text example 5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 6</h3>
      <p>Text example 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="links_2">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 7</h3>
      <p>Text example 7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 8</h3>
      <p>Text example 8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 9</h3>
      <p>Text example 9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 10</h3>
      <p>Text example 10</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 11</h3>
      <p>Text example 11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 12</h3>
      <p>Text example 12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="links_3">
    <div>
      <h3>Header 13</h3>
      <p>Text example 13</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 14</h3>
      <p>Text example 14</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 15</h3>
      <p>Text example 15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Header 16</h3>
      <p>Text example 16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This would work fine, as long as you want the items to run in horizontal rows instead of vertical columns.